# How do I create instances of my classes in Prism4 MEF?

Tags: c#, prism, mef, prism-4

I have configured container:

```
public class MyBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper  
{  
    protected override void ConfigureAggregateCatalog()
    {
        AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(xxx.Assembly));
// other assemblies
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (MainWindow)Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.GetExportedValue<MainWindow>();
    }
}
```

How can I create instance of my type T in module? Type T is defined somewhere in assemblies, that are configured by MEF.

I need some like this:

```
var myType = XXXX.Resolve<T>();
```

UPD1.
MyModule

```
[ModuleExport(typeof(CatalogModule))]
public class CatalogModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _event;
    private readonly IUIManager _uiManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CatalogModule(IEventAggregator @event, IUIManager uiManager)
    {
        _event = @event;
        _uiManager = uiManager;
    }

    private void Foo()
    {
        var vm = **How create instance of desired type here?**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do that the same way you got an instance of `MainWindow` in the `CreateShell` method override. All you have to do is call `Container.GetExportedValue<T>()`, which allows you to get an instance directly. If, however, you want to have a type injected, for more loose coupling, you need to have a constructor with and `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute that depends on that type (or preferably, an Interface), or a property of that type with an `[Import]` attribute.

Make sure that you have your type exported, by decorating the class with a `[Export]` attribute, and that the assembly is added to the `AggregateCatalog`.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Yes. Buh how can I get 'Container'? In module I don't know anything about it.

Comment: You can have your module depend on the MEF Container which is of type `CompositionContainer` (by adding it to the `ImportingConstructor`). Make sure you register the container instance in the bootstrapper with itself. (`Container.ComposeExportedValue(Container);`). The container will be injected to your constructor and you'll have access to all exports ;)